# Ajax Laravel8 - auto populate fields based on selected dropdown value not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a simple form page where I want to display the details of a client based on the selected client, I am a newbie to ajax and I've had this problem for quite some time and I really can't get to make it work.

Note: "Nume" is not a typo, its the way I included it in my db instead of name
Also:  id ='sel_depart' is the id of the selected client
And,  name="sel_emp" id="sel_emp" is where I want his details to be displayed (which is "iban")

This is my controller:

```
public function getClientspay( Request $request, $id){
      $clientsid = $request->clientsid;
      $clients = clients::select('*')->where('id', $clientsid)->get();
     $response['data'] = $clients;
     
     return response()->json($response);
    }
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/getClientspay', [PlatiController::class,'getClientspay']);
```

This is the part of the form where I want to display it:

```
<div class="row">
<label for="">Nume Client</label>
<label for="">Introduceti ID</label>
<select id ='sel_depart' name='sel_depart' >
@foreach ($clients as $clients)
 

 <option   name='search' value="{{$clients->id}}">{{$clients->nume}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
<select name="sel_emp" id="sel_emp">
<option value="0"></option>


</select>
```

And this is my ajax request

```
 $('#sel_depart').change(function(){

         // Department id
         var id = $(this).val();

         // Empty the dropdown
         $('#sel_emp').find('option').not(':first').remove();

         // AJAX request 
         $.ajax({
           url: 'getClientspay',
           type: 'get',
           data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, clientsid: clientsid},
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(response){

             var len = 0;
             if(response['data'] != null){
               len = response['data'].length;
             }

             if(len > 0){
               // Read data and create <option >
               for(var i=0; i<len; i++){

                 var id = response['data'][i].id;
                 var iban = response['data'][i].iban ;

                 var option = "<option value='"+id+"'>"+iban+"</option>"; 

                 $("#sel_emp").append(option); 
               }
             }

           }
        });
      });

    });
```

Comment: First of all, are you trying to get all clients or just a clinet with the $id? Because you are adding where clause with id and assigning it to $clients but it should be 1 client because id is unique, then you are iterating it in your view the same key foreach ($clients as $clients)
 which is not correct. It should be foreach ($clients as $client)

Comment: Yes, I changed to foreach ($clients as $client), but I am trying to get the data of the specific user selected only

Answer (score 1):

I need more information.
Please open Browser Developer Tools (usually F12) from the page with the form and check both "Console" and "Network" tabs while changing the select.
From there it is possible to understand and fix your issue.

Edit: Thanks for posting more information.

As I can see you have error in your ajax. You are passing an undefined variable 'clinetsid'. I guess that variable should contain client ID which is the value coming from select. You are already taking that value and need to pass it in ajax data.

Let me explain with code:

```
$('#sel_depart').change(function(){

     // Department id
     var id = $(this).val(); **//this is your select value (client id)**

     // Empty the dropdown
     $('#sel_emp').find('option').not(':first').remove();

     // AJAX request 
     $.ajax({
       url: 'getClientspay',
       type: 'get',
       data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, clientsid: id}, **//Here you need to pass it**
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(response){

         var len = 0;
         if(response['data'] != null){
           len = response['data'].length;
         }

         if(len > 0){
           // Read data and create <option >
           for(var i=0; i<len; i++){

             var id = response['data'][i].id;
             var iban = response['data'][i].iban ;

             var option = "<option value='"+id+"'>"+iban+"</option>"; 

             $("#sel_emp").append(option); 
           }
         }

       }
    });
  });

});
```

Please accept my answer if correct.

Comment: If a clarification from the question is needed, it's better to leave a comment on the question itself, and not as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: The interface did not allow me. Sorry for the noobness regarding the use.

Comment: No worries! It's because you have not enough reputation, this comes with a bit more interaction with the platform. In this regard would be better to wait for somebody else to add a comment or flag the question and not to answer (as you're not really answering to it because of the quality of the question itself). The worse thing that can happen is that you get down-votes, is not a terrible thing but can be avoided easily :)

Comment: I inform you that I can only comment under my own posts. Rules are arbitrary here, huh?
I can only post replies or questions. Nothing else is admitted. I understand your point but only confirmed members can do other kind of stuff. New questions are often missing data so it is impossible to ask without posting an answer.
I'm only trying to get some points and start following the rules, but community is not helping this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    use App\Models\Client;


    public function getClientspay(Request $request, $id){

    return response()->json(['client' => Client::where('id', $id)->first()]); // this will return specific user.
}
```

And remove your foreach loop for $clients inside your view. Just use $client. If you are using blade and don't need json just return $client variable to your view.